# I'm not able to send message to socket server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sockets, ios6

I have to create a **chat app** for `iOS` using **socket programming** .

I'm not able to receive and send data ,there are no error or crash.

My code :

```
-(IBAction)sendButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSString *ipAddress = @"my server ip address";
    NSString *portNo = @"my port number";

    if(inputStream && outputStream)
       [self close];

    NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:ipAddress];

    if (!website)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ is not a valid URL", website);
    }
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) [website host], [portNo intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);

    self.inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
    self.outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    NSLog(@"inputStream ===%@",inputStream);
    NSLog(@"outputStream ===%@",outputStream);

    [self open];
}

- (void)open
{
    [self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [self.outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                            forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                             forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.inputStream open];
    [self.outputStream open];

    NSLog(@"Socket Init: %@",@"");
}

- (void)dataSending:(NSString*)data
{
    NSLog(@"data ===%@",data);

    if(outputStream)
    {
        if(![outputStream hasSpaceAvailable])
            return;
        NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<EOF>",data];

        NSLog(@"response ===--------------->%@",response);

        NSData *msgdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

        NSLog(@"msgdata ===--------------->%@",msgdata);
        [outputStream write:[msgdata bytes] maxLength:[msgdata length]];

        NSLog(@"Sent data----------------------%@",data);
       }
}

-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
     NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

    NSString *event;
    switch (streamEvent)
    {
        case NSStreamEventNone:
            event = @"NSStreamEventNone";
            break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            event = @"NSStreamEventOpenCompleted";
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            event = @"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable";
            if (theStream == inputStream)
            {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;
                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
                {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
                    if (len > 0)
                    {
                        NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                                               initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                        NSLog(@"Received data--------------------%@", output);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            event = @"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable";
            [self dataSending:self.messageTextFiled.text];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            event = @"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred"; 
            [self close];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            event = @"NSStreamEventEndEncountered";
            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [self close];
            break;
        default:
            event = @"Unknown";
            break;
     }
      NSLog(@"event------%@",event);
 }
```

I have tried a lot and googled ,but I did not find any solution.
 It's killing my time so if any one have worked on it please guide me and post sample code.

Comment: Did you get two NSStreamEventOpenCompleted events, and did you get NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable event shortly after you opened the streams?

Comment: Now, consider that when you got an `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event you need to either actually write at least one byte or REMEMBER that the stream can accept bytes. When you do not write after that event, you'll not get it again. So, possibly you need to change your logic. But first check IFF you write something, that a) it goes through the wire to the server, and then b) once you have something written and the input stream is NOT full, that you get a following `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event.

Comment: in my logic where i did wrong

Comment: There's nothing wrong yet. But you cannot yet accomplish to write without issues: you need an intermediate "send buffer". From the text field, you insert the data, and from your "send buffer logic" you take that input and write them - possibly in _chunks_ to the stream. Now, when the "send buffer logic" has written all data, your stream events are pausing - since there is no state change. Now, when the user enters more text, you need to "resume" the stream events, by explicitly writing into the stream (which changes the state of the stream, and triggers events).

Comment: The reason you need that intermediate "send buffer" is to be able to write larger chunks of text than the internal buffer of the output stream can hold.

Comment: Hint: to simply check whether the output stream works is to just send one byte in the case statement `case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:` - instead of reading from the text field. Check also if the bytes are received on the server.